# Building Mongodb 3.0.0 with SSL

Tags: ssl, mongodb

I am trying to build Mongodb 3.0.0-rc8 (tried latest nightly too) with ssl support.
I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/emgee3/0852cccc1a1fd1c418d3) which works for 2.6.7 but when I run it with 3.0.0-rc8 I get that eror

```
src/mongo/crypto/crypto_tom.cpp:30:2: error: #error This file should not be included if compiling with SSL support
```

I am building it in docker so the environment should be fairly standard.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some try and error (Thanks @wesley that put me on the right path), there is a [known bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14811) where if you try to  build all the different target despite what you specify if you put the source in the parent folder of where you want to install them.
I put my source in /usr/src/mongo and the target is /usr/
So I assume it try to build the non ssl as well as the ssl version.
Once I put my source in ~ in worked like a charm.
Hope it will help someone else with the same non descriptive error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file `crypto_tom.cpp` and try again.